# NSString boolValue return nil

Tags: objective-c

Never mind, I was doing "po x" instead of "p x" in debugger. tnx!

Why is this not returning NO :

```
BOOL x = [@"0" boolValue];
```

According to documentation:

> @property(readonly) BOOL boolValue
>   Discussion
>   This property is YES on encountering one of "Y", "y", "T", "t", or a digit 1-9—the method ignores any trailing characters. This property is NO if the receiver doesn’t begin with a valid decimal text representation of a number.

Comment: Show how you are determining the value of `x`.

Comment: How do you distinguish `NO` from `nil`??  (BOOL is not an object type.)

Comment: @Ramshad - So how would you tell?  What is the difference between `NO` and `nil`?

Comment: @david72: `po` is to print NSObjects and BOOL is a primitive type. So you need to use `p`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check like below, you can understand the documentation description.

```
BOOL x = [@"0" boolValue];

if (x)
   NSLog(@"x is YES");
else
   NSLog(@"x is NO");
```

or use the log as below,

```
NSLog(@"%@", x ? @"YES" : @"NO");
```

Comment: Do not compare a `BOOL` value to `YES` or `NO`. Simply do `if (x)`.

Comment: And you can't use `%@` with `BOOL`.

Comment: @rmaddy: thank you for the corrections. I have modified my answer.

Comment: Ok, but why expression `self.Property = ([[Soap getNodeValue: node withName: @"NodeName"] boolValue])?YES:NO;` gives `nil`, @rmaddy?

Comment: @new2ios 1) It can't give `nil`. It can only give `YES` or `NO`. Note that `NO` and `nil` are essentially the same thing. 2) There is no reason at all to use such an expression. Just do `self.Property = [[Soap getNodeValue: node withName: @"NodeName"] boolValue];`. I'm assuming that `self.Property` is of type `BOOL`. 3) If you have a new question, post a new question. These comments are not the place to ask a completely new question.

Comment: 10x @rmaddy, I understand that yesterday. I use `po` to in which case `nil` is correct, because I have object (SILLY ME) :). I asked because I received several times duplicated. I think that the question is close to my problem. 10x again. Next time I will ask new question.